# Chainlink VRF : can't get a Random array

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I'm trying to edit this demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqZWariqh5s
to get a array with ramdom number.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/master/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    uint256 public randomResult;
    
    constructor() VRFConsumerBase(
            0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9, // VRF Coordinator
            0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088  // LINK Token
        ) public
    {
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }
    

    function getRandomNumber(uint256 userProvidedSeed) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userProvidedSeed);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness.mod(50).add(1);
    }
    
    function getDraw(uint256 userProvidedSeed) public returns(uint256[] memory) {
         uint256[] memory draw = new uint256[](5);
         
         for(uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             draw[i] = getRandomNumber(userProvidedSeed);
         }
         return draw;
    }
}
```

I get this error :
**contracts/RandomNumbers.sol:33:24: TypeError: Type bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256. draw[i] = getRandomNumber(userProvidedSeed); ^-------------------------------^**

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a bytes32 to a uint256.

Your `draw` array is an array of `uint256`s. `getRandomNumber` returns a `bytes32`.

On this line:

```
draw[i] = getRandomNumber(userProvidedSeed);
```

You're setting `draw[i]` to a `bytes32`. `draw[i]` needs to be a `uint256` and `getRandomNumber(userProvidedSeed)` returns a `bytes32`

See:

```
function getRandomNumber(uint256 userProvidedSeed) public returns (bytes32 requestId)
```

What you may want to do instead, is have your drawing happen in the `fulfillrandomness` function, since it looks like you want to do:

```
draw[i] = randomResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

`getRandomNumber()` returns `bytes32`, but you're trying to assign this value to `uint256`.

You need to cast the `bytes32` to `uint256` first:

```
draw[i] = uint256(getRandomNumber(userProvidedSeed));
```

---

*Note: `requestRandomness()` returns the request ID, not the actual random number. So if you want to get actual 5 random numbers from an oracle, you **cannnot do it synchronously**. You'll also need to update your `fulfillRandomness()` and `randomResult` to store more than one value.*